# getting Exponential dates while using as.yearqtr in R

Tags: r

I have date set as below.

```
Created.Date    Supply.Date  Revenue
1/27/2014     8/1/2011        12232
1/27/2014     8/1/2011        45280
1/27/2013     8/1/2011        57512
8/27/2013     8/1/2011        102792
5/27/2013     8/1/2011        160304
5/27/2013     8/1/2011        263096
4/27/2014     8/1/2011        423400
11/20/2014    8/1/2011        686496
3/10/2015     8/1/2011        1109896
7/19/2015     8/1/2011        1796392
12/10/2012    8/1/2011        2906288
8/10/2012     8/1/2011        4702680
3/10/2012     8/1/2011        7608968
```

I used the following code:

```
require(zoo)
df.CD.SSD$Created.Date = as.yearqtr(df.CD.SSD$Created.Date, format = "%yQ%q")
```

but the Output is not of the required format.
The output is as below.

```
Created.Date     Supply.Date     Revenue
2.014e+01 Q1e+00    6/19/2011   12232
2.013e+01 Q1e+00    8/1/2011    45280
2.013e+05 Q2e+00    8/1/2011    57512
2.013e+08 Q3e+00    8/1/2011    102792
```

I would like to have the Output to be "2013 / Q1", "2014 / Q2".

Any help in resolving this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
df.CD.SSD$Created.Date <- as.yearqtr(df.CD.SSD$Created.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

but this is only the first part of the solution. As pointed out by @G.Grothendieck in a comment, the desired format if obtained by using
    `df.CD.SSD$Created.Date <- format(as.yearqtr(df.CD.SSD$Created.Date, "%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y / Q%q")`

```
#> head(df.CD.SSD)
#   Created.Date Supply.Date Revenue
#1     2014 / Q1    8/1/2011   12232
#2     2014 / Q1    8/1/2011   45280
#3     2013 / Q1    8/1/2011   57512
#4     2013 / Q3    8/1/2011  102792
#5     2013 / Q2    8/1/2011  160304
#6     2013 / Q2    8/1/2011  263096
```

Comment: That's definitely better, @G.Grothendieck ;-)

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I think the use of the `format` argument in `as.yearqtr` could be more explicitly described in `?as.yearqtr`. The only argument described in `zoo 1.7-12` is `...`, which is "Currently not used". Perhaps add an example as well? Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion both Grothendieck and Hertel. It worked. The mistake i did was I had used options("scipen"=-100, "digits"=4) in the code as well.

Again thanks both of you.

Comment: @Henrik, Achim has updated the help file in the development version.